# How to prevent other users from stopping / removing my docker container

Tags: linux, docker

In a simplified version:
There are two users on our shared Server System:

`user_1 (me)
 user_2`

Docker is installed system-wide across users.

I `user_1`, created a docker container using standard `docker run` running my process. But `user_2` has access to this container thereby he/she can not only view, but also stop and remove my container.

How can I prevent `user_2` or other users from accessing this container.
**Note: No users have root access through sudo.**. Thanks!

Comment: `user_2` is free to `docker run --rm -v /:/host busybox vi /host/etc/sudoers`, and now everybody has access via sudo.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: No users have root access through sudo

If users have access to the docker socket, they all have root access on the host. You've lost all security at that point. If you don't believe this, see what access you have in /host with:

```
docker run --privileged --net=host --pid=host -v /:/host debian /bin/bash
```

There are projects to limit access to the docker socket with authz plugins, including twistlock and open policy agent. There's quite a bit of setup needed for these, including revoking access to the socket from the filesystem and using tls keys to access an encrypted and authenticated port. You could also go the commercial route and use docker EE with UCP to manage users and their access rights.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanatory answer. I know that this setup is not the best in terms of user security for now, but we just need a system in place that doesn't allow users to stop other users' processes (containers) on the system. Our use case is a bit different, so allowing file access is fine for now. Thanks

Comment: @AnimeshKarnewar Allowing users unrestricted access to the docker socket (file access) means not only can they run docker commands to interfere with other users, but they can impact the underlying host as the root user. E.g. they can still `kill $pid` in the above example stop any process outside of the container.